# Typescript reduce I want to sum numbers but the previous value becomes string

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a typescript function which traverse an array of objects, and summary them.
It was working if I implicit gives the value a number, however if it comes from input it converts the value to string.

```
const mmrChanges = matches.reduce<IHistory[]>(
     (previous: IHistory[], match: IMatch, index: number) => {
       const mmrChange = (match.party_size > 1 ? 20 : 30) * isWon(match); // party game 20 mmr, solo game 30
       const prevMmr = previous[previous.length - 1].value;
       return [
         ...previous,
         {
           index: index,
           value: prevMmr + mmrChange,
           time: new Date(match.start_time * 1000).toISOString().split("T")[0],
         },
       ];
     },
     [{ index: 0, value: currentMmr, time: "" }]
   );
   console.log(mmrChanges);
```

value type is : (property) IHistory.value: number
and the current mmr is: const currentMmr: number

However when I start to accumulate the value numbers it starts to concatenate values as strings.
currentValue = 400

the next iterate it becomes:

```
{
    "index": 0,
    "value": "40030",
    "time": "2022-01-25"
}
```

I tried to force it to number explicitly inside the reduce function with "as number"
Also I tried the parseInt() function, but then typescript throws error I cant transform number to int.

What am I missing here?
If I change the currentMmr to 0 it is working as intended.

Comment: Were are you assigning `currentMmr`?

Comment: What happens if this: `[{ index: 0, value: currentMmr, time: "" }]` is replaced as: `[{ index: 0, value: parseInt(currentMmr) || 0, time: "" }]`

Comment: `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

Comment: `[{ index: 0, value: parseInt(currentMmr.toString()) || 0, time: "" }]` <-- hopefully this should work irrespective of whether `currentMmr` is a number or a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution below seem to have achieved the desired results:

```
const mmrChanges = matches.reduce<IHistory[]>(
     (previous: IHistory[], match: IMatch, index: number) => {
       const mmrChange = (match.party_size > 1 ? 20 : 30) * isWon(match); // party game 20 mmr, solo game 30
       const prevMmr = previous[previous.length - 1].value;
       return [
         ...previous,
         {
           index: index,
           value: prevMmr + mmrChange,
           time: new Date(match.start_time * 1000).toISOString().split("T")[0],
         },
       ];
     },
     [{ index: 0, value: parseInt(currentMmr.toString()) || 0, time: "" }]
   );
console.log(mmrChanges);
```

**What changed?**

The `.reduce` aggregator was set to `[{ index: 0, value: parseInt(currentMmr.toString()) || 0, time: "" }]`

**Why?**

In the question, `currentMmr` could be any value. In order to ensure that it is always an int, the `value` prop is set as `parseInt(currentMmr.toString())`. The `.toString()` ensures that in case `currentMmr` is an integer, it is still treated as a string. And, the `parseInt` transforms the string into an int.

Note: This solution caters to this particular question. It may not work **AS IS** in other contexts and may need to be customized.